# Put message in the end of a element, using a directive. in Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have any checkboxes, i need put a string "MESSAGE IN THE END" in the end of theses checkboxes.
how can I do it?

```
     <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="my_check"  validate />
     <br>
     <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="my_check"  validate />
     <br>
     <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="my_check"  validate />
     <br>
     <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="my_check"  validate />

app.directive('validate', function ($timeout,$compile) {

 return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel', 

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                if (!ngModel){
            return;          
      }            
    ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val){
        var element_delete= angular.element( document.querySelector( '#errormy_check' ) )
                element_delete.remove();
                var newDirective = angular.element('<div id="errormy_check">MESSAGE IN THE END</div>');
                element.after(newDirective);
                $compile(newDirective)(scope);
                ngModel.$render();
        return false; 
    })
    }

  };
});
```

I need this!
 I want to put this message at the end of all checkboxes, every time the user changes the value of a checkbox.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/w7vy9kbt/

Comment: is the message different depending on the checkbox(es) selected?

Comment: no, is the same, i need that message when any checkbox is changed.

Comment: but, this message must be in the end of the all checkbox

Comment: then why are you trying to use a directive at all?  just use `ng-show`.

Comment: @Claies No, this is a small example for something I need

Comment: it's not clear what you need at all.  a directive doesn't make sense for what you are describing, and it's not obvious what you might be doing differently that would require a directive.

Comment: @Claies It is true. But I have a project where I actually need this in a directive. But in that project I have a problem that would be solved, with the answer to this question. okay?

Comment: need the directive to do *what*?  It's not possible to answer a question telling you how to create a directive when it's not clear what the directive is supposed to do, or use of a directive wouldn't be appropriate for what you describe.  You clearly think a directive is necessary for some reason, but your question doesn't make it clear why that is.  just using a directive because you want to doesn't make it something that makes sense to do.....

Comment: besides the fact that based on your example in this question, you don't understand how directives affect the DOM anyway;  you have 4 copies of the directive here, but you only want one output in the DOM, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Claies My friend, simply. I need a message at the end of all the checkboxes. That will help me. I have a bigger problem and this will solve it. trust me.

Comment: a single message at the end of the checkboxes would not require a directive on every checkbox.  period.

Comment: @Claies In this case no. But seriously I have a very broad directive in a real project, and something like that can serve me. I appreciate your feedback, but I really need to know how to do this.

Comment: you are totally missing the point.  THIS IS NOT SOMETHING THAT CAN WORK THE WAY YOU HAVE PRESENTED IT.  You can't have 4 copies of a directive that only manipulate 1 element in the DOM.  Now, if you would describe something of what your real need is, that would be different, but just saying "I need to know this for some reason that I can't explain" doesn't make the solution suddenly something that can work.  on the contrary, it makes your question an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).

Comment: @Claies You are giving a lot of questions. In a directive, I need to put a message at the end of the checkboxes. It should be possible, if I ask the complete question according to my problem, I do not think I am able to recreate it in a jsdfiddle....

Comment: you still haven't described why your directive can't update a value that can be monitored by a simple `ng-show`.  also, you make it sound like the directive you have contains the checkboxes, but here you show one directive per checkbox.

Comment: @Claies You're very nice because you're trying to bring me something good. But understand my reasons, if I know how to solve this, I could apply it in my real project. In my real project I have a directive that does many things, but I have a problem that would be solved by this.

Comment: I wish you luck, but it seems like I really won't be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing all message elements instead of a specific one.

```
var element_delete= angular.element( document.querySelector( '#errormy_check' ) );
```

it should be,

```
var element_delete = element.next('#errormy_check');
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {});

app.directive('validate', function($timeout, $compile) {

  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',

    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) {
        return;
      }
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        var element_delete = element.next('#errormy_check');
        element_delete.remove();
        var newDirective = angular.element('<div id="errormy_check">MESSAGE IN THE END</div>');
        element.after(newDirective);
        $compile(newDirective)(scope);
        ngModel.$render();
        return false;
      })
    }

  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="app">
  <article ng-controller="appCtrl" class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal well" name="form">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="my_check" validate />
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="my_check" validate />
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="my_check" validate />
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="my_check" validate />
    </form>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: it not works for me! i need create the message in the end of the all the checkboxes